# Android, не получается интегрировать Dagger2, "Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor "

Tags: android, dagger2

Хочу интегрировать Dagger2, не могу собрать проект, падаю с ошибкой:

```
error: com.example.animalslibrary.ui.home.activity.HomeActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
com.example.animalslibrary.ui.home.activity.HomeActivity is injected at
com.example.animalslibrary.AppComponent.injectsHomeActivity(homeActivity)
```

Помогите понять в чём дело, голову сломал уже.

Мои действия поэтапно:

1) Добавил зависимости в Gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
```

2) Создал пустой тестовый класс `NetworkUtils`

```
public class NetworksUtils {
}
```

3) Создал для него модуль `NetworksModule`:

```
@Module
public class NetworksModule {
    @Provides
    NetworksUtils provideNetworksUtils() {
        return new NetworksUtils();
    }
}
```

4) Создал "связующий" интерфейс `AppComponent`

```
import dagger.Component;

@Component(modules = NetworksModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void injectsHomeActivity(HomeActivity homeActivity);
}
```

5) Создал класс `App`, пока что не совсем понимаю зачем(иду по гайду). Вернее не понимаю зачем мне `Application` расширять. DaggerAppComponent помечен красным, т.к проект не собирается и этот класс не создаётся.

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static AppComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = DaggerAppComponent.create();
    }

    public static AppComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

6) Добавил `App` класс в манифест:

```
 <application
        android:name="com.example.animalslibrary.ui.App"
        ...
```

7) В `HomeActivity` пишу:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
HomeContract.View {
...
@Inject
private NetwotkUtils netwotkUtils;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ...
    App.getComponent().injectsHomeActivity(this);
    ...
    }
}
```

8) Собираю билд, падаю.

Я подозреваю что виновник - класс `App`, но уличить его пока ни в чём не могу. В `HomeActivity` инжектирую только `NetworksUtils`, больше ничего с даггером у меня не связанно.

**UPD:** Модификация:

```
public class NetwotkUtils {
    @Inject
    public NetwotkUtils() {
    }
}
```

Не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задал аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном форуме, есть ответ:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955755/android-cant-integrate-dagger2-bacause-of-error-activity-cannot-be-provided-w/54955864#54955864

Перевод:

---

В твоём коде две проблемы, одна из них является причиной твоей ошибки.

Во первых, то должен включить твой модуль в процесс сборки своего приложения:

`component = DaggerAppComponent.create();`

Во вторых, `Dagger` НЕ инжектирует приватные поля.

Пример первого пункта:

```
component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
   .networkModule(new NetworkModule())
   .build()
```

---

Дополнительно ещё сменил версию `Dagger2` на 2.21

Answer (score 0):

```
component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().setNetworksModule(NetworksModule()).build()
```

Добавь в App модуль

Так же попробуй убрать static из App

```
private static AppComponent component;
```

Comment: Нет, не помогает. `DaggerAppComponent` не компилируется же, т.к проект не собирается.
На всякий случай: https://ibb.co/g46hNsQ

Comment: @KirstenLy, попробуй удалить код из HomeActivity, после чего запусти сборку проекта. Далее попробуй собрать через builder

Comment: Что то типа такого должно получится: DaggerAppComponent.builder().setNetworksModule(NetworksModule()).build()

Comment: Нет, даже без кода в активити не собирается проект.

Comment: Удаление `static` тоже не помогло. У меня видимо какой - то особый случай =)